# Creating Shared libraries in PHP

Tags: php, libraries, code-reuse

Im working on a few php based projects and im having an issue of **having to maintain separate code bases with common code**. The common code shared amongst all the projects is added physically (file are copied in the folder) and when a change is needed we have to manually replicate the fixes in the common code functionality in each project.

In java we can create a library (jar file) and share it among different projects. 
Is there any shared library related concept available in PHP 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also been pondering the same problem. Here are some thoughts.

Approaches

1: Set the include path to one shared folder from all your projects. It shouldn't break anything if you're careful about backward compatibility while writing/modifying your library. But yes it's very risky because if you do break something, it will be broken on all your projects.

2: Create a simple update script included with your library that copies the files from the main source to your project. Run this script when you update the library.

3: Use a version control setup. Git submodules might work ( http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html )

4: Phar files are something I'd like to try. It's only drawback is that they don't work with PHP versions lower than 5.3

UPDATE: 04/12/2011 - I recommend using approach #3. Now that I've used it for a while, it seems to be clearly the best practice.

Comment: well, sorry i never updated this thread or closed it, i actually used svn:external property to get this done. so now i just referece the library project in the other projects, and if i change in one, it changes in all of them

Comment: I've been using approach #3 above with Git submodules. (I believe svn:external is the equivalent in SVN). I'm convinced this is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

PHP's version of a jar is called Phar:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to check the shared code into a version control repository, and check it out into the projects? For example, SVN supports that with the [`svn:externals` property](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/svn-book.html#svn-ch-7-sect-3)

Comment: well, sorry i never updated this thread, i actually used svn:external property to get this done

Answer (score 1):

Although PHP now supports phar files, the right way to solve the problem is by using include files (and paths) effectively.

The include path is always searched in the same order for files - so a good practice is to to have 2 hierarchies defined, one for the scope of the code (e.g. everything, application, module) and one for the environment where it is running (holding such things as related URLs, batabase connections etc e.g. everything, environment (development / test / live), cluster node)

C.